# DEAP: what does the indpb parameter do in the mutPolynomialBounded function?

Tags: python, deap

The [DEAP documentation](https://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/tools.html#deap.tools.mutPolynomialBounded) states that `deap.tools.mutPolynomialBounded` takes five parameters. However, only the first four are described. Why is `indpb` needed?

In [the code](https://github.com/DEAP/deap/blob/454b4f65a9c944ea2c90b38a75d384cddf524220/deap/tools/mutation.py#L51), it appears to be the mutation probability, but how is it different from the mutation probability that is specified when calling `eaSimple` for instance?

How is having these two mutation probabilities different from having just one mutation probability that is `mutpb * indpb` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DEAP, `indpb` is the probability of a gene changing its original value to its allele. `mutpb`, on the other hand, determines whether an individual (chromosome) will mutate at all.

So, after crossover, each offspring (child/new individual) needs to first detemine whether it mutates or not, i.e., `random.random() < mutpb`. If yes, then `indpb` will actually determine how many genes in the offspring (child) are actually get changed, i.e., `random.random() <= indpb`.

A dummy example: let's say, you have an offspring `[1, 3, 2, 2, 1]`. The `indpb` will control how many and which values in here get changed. However, whether this offspring is actually going to *mutate* **or not** is up to `mutpb`.